# How to integrate R code in sklearn Pipeline?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, time-series, pipeline

I have a complex approach with separate models and Stacker on top of them. Like:

```
# GLMNET
glmnet_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("DATA_CLEANER", DataCleaner(demo='HH_F', mode='strict')),
    ("DATA_ENCODING", Encoder(encoder_name='code')),
    ("MODELLING", glm)
])
# XGBoost 
xgb_1_pipe = Pipeline([
    ("DATA_CLEANER", DataCleaner(demo='HH_F', mode='strict')),
    ("DATA_ENCODING", Encoder(encoder_name='code')),
    ("SCALE", Normalizer(normalizer=NORMALIZE)),
    ("FEATURE_SELECTION", huber_feature_selector),
    ("MODELLING", xgb_1)
])
# set of our models
base_models = [glmnet_pipe, xgb1_pipe]
# using Stacker on top of those ones
StackingRegressor(
  regressors=base_models,
  meta_regressor=SVR()
)
```

However, I have also a pipeline implemented in R with `forecast` package. All my R results are little bit "unique" in terms of speed of implementation/rewriting to Python.

Are there any approaches to incorporate R code to `sklearn`?

So far, I see following possibility:

```
import subprocess

CustomRModel = class():

  def __init__(self, path, args):
    self.path = path
    self.args = args
    self.cmd = ['RScript', self.path] + self.args

  def fit(self, X, Y):
    # call fit in R
    subprocess.check_output(self.cmd, universal_newlines=True)
    # read ouput of R.csv to Python dataframe
    # pd.read_csv
    return self

  def predict(X):
    # call predict in R
    subprocess.check_output(self.cmd, universal_newlines=True)
    # read ouput of R.csv to Python dataframe
    # pd.read_csv
    # calculate predict
    return predict
```

and later use that class as usual step in Pipeline.

Or maybe do you know more cool approaches?